# Make a iframe load full screen on clicking another youtube iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a YouTube iframe-like shown below, and I'm trying to replicate a similar behavior to what is seen with the iframe on this website: https://www.tella.tv.

```
<body>

     <iframe id="my-video" class="iframe__video" height="80vh" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_oqy0-lvI4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<script src="js/youtube.js"></script>

</body>
```

```
var done = false;
var player;

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    console.log("onPlayerStateChange...................")
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
        done = true;
        var iframe = document.getElementById("my-video");
        iframe.style.display = "none"; // Hide the original iframe
        var newIframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        newIframe.setAttribute("src", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_oqy0-lvI4?autoplay=1");
        newIframe.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", "");
        newIframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
        newIframe.style.position = "fixed";
        newIframe.style.top = "0";
        newIframe.style.left = "0";
        newIframe.style.width = "100vw";
        newIframe.style.height = "100vh";
        document.body.appendChild(newIframe);
    }
}

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    console.log("onYouTubeIframeAPIReady..............")
    player = new YT.Player("my-video", {
        events: {
            onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}

window.onload = function() {
    console.log("onLoad.......................")
    var tag = document.createElement("script");
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var myVideo = document.getElementById("my-video");
    myVideo.onclick = function() {
        player.playVideo();
    }
};
```

But when I'm clicking the youtube play button, nothing is happening. This event "onPlayerStateChange" is also not getting triggered. I can see the other 2 fns getting triggered --onYouTubeIframeAPIReady and onLoad

Comment: What "similar behavior"?

Comment: On Clicking the iframe, an iframe opens in a popup occupying much bigger screen